# retrieve data from sql table through c++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

as the title says i want to do the following:

I created (in sql) a table "radiation" which is :

[image]

Now, i want from c++ to be able to ask the user "Give an element " and if the user gives for example "I" then retrieve the "halftime" field for example.

The c++ code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{ 


MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL *connection, mysql;

const char* server="127.0.0.1";
const char* user ="****";
const char* password="****";
const char* database="***";

int state;

mysql_init(&mysql);

connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,server,user,password,database,0,0,0);

if (connection == NULL)
    {

cout<<mysql_error(&mysql);

return 1;
    }

state = mysql_query(connection, "SELECT * FROM radiation");

if (state !=0)
    {
    cout <<mysql_error(connection);
   return 1;
    }

result = mysql_store_result(connection);


row=mysql_fetch_row(result);
string name;

cout <<"\nGive the name : "<<endl;
cin >>name;

cout << "\nThe halftime for "<<name << " is "<<**row[2]**->here i want to extract the analogous filed <<" hours";
//}



mysql_free_result(result);

mysql_close(connection);


return 0;
}
```

I know only the basics from sql , i don't know how difficult is to do the above.

Comment: What's the question?  How difficult is it?  You've provided some code, so does that code work?  What problems specifically with the code are you having?

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? What's result of running the code?

Comment: The wrong with my code is that i use "row[2]"to retrieve the result.But i want the program to recognize the name that i give (ex."I") and retrieve the right column from the right field .

Answer (score 2):

Based on the clarification in your comment, you simply need to build your SQL statement properly:

```
SELECT halftime FROM RADIATION WHERE name_id = 'Tc'
```

Will give the result as:

```
6
```

For a more complex answer:

```
std::string column;
std::string name;

// have the user tell you what columns are wanted
cin >> column;

// have the user give you the criteria
cin >> name;

// build the SQL
std::stringstream sql;

sql << "SELECT " << column << " FROM RADIATION WHERE name = '" << name << "'";
```

Comment: :Hello, i want the user to enter a name (for ex."I") and then get the result i want.Also,not necessary halftime.Please,see above what i want.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  What you want to do is not difficult, you just have to build the SQL string properly.

Comment: :1) In the string column i write for ex. "halftime" and in "name" i write "I".How i get the results?I mean ,if i try "cout<<sql"it gives me an address.  2) I don't want the user to enter "column".I want to just enter "I" and the program gets (uses)the halftime for example.Thank you!

Comment: If halftime is only the example, how do you know what column(s) you want to display?  `cout << sql.str();` will display the contents of your SQL string.  You have to pass this string to your `mysql` database.

Comment: As i said before,i want the user to input a name(ex."I") and retrieve from the database the "halftime"in order to show the result (or make calculations with "halftime").If i do "cout <<sql.str()"it doesn't show the value of halftime ,just the name halftime.I hope i am telling it right in order to understand.

Comment: You're right it doesn't.  See the answer below on how to actually extract data from the database, or look at one of the many C++ tutorials on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

[This may help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html). You just have to process the result set that you get after executing your query.

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM radiation");
while (res->next()) {
  // You can use either numeric offsets...
  cout << "name_id = " << res->getInt(1); // getInt(1)/getString() returns the first column
      }
```

Comment: @:Hello,i can't figure how to do it because i am getting a lot of errors.Do you have in mind another tutorial for that?